# Angular $http post with data:image/png;base64 field

Tags: angularjs, rest, django-rest-framework

I have built an Angular app with Django Rest Framework as a backend.

In the user profile edit page, it contains the picture cropping using [ngImgCrop](https://github.com/alexk111/ngImgCrop). Then I got the cropped image result as **data:image/png;base64**.

But when I call $http patch in the controller to update the picture at the server side I always got **400 Bad Request** "The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form.". and I think it come from data:image/png;base64.

Here is my angular code. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this? Or I did something wrong?

```
$http({
  method : 'PATCH',
  url : ,
  data : {
    profile_picture: $scope.croppedProfilePicture
  }
}).then(function () {
  ...
});
```

I also attempt to add some headers for this request, but still have no luck.

```
headers : {'Content-Type': undefined }
```

Comment: were you able to POST the image first? Also, what specifically is the error the server is throwing?

Comment: @user2954587 Thank for your help. Both POST and PATCH are got the same error.

Comment: can you please post the error message?

Comment: @user2954587 Error 400 Bad request "The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form".

Comment: I just try to send the request the content-type = form-data header and it's work. Maybe this problem occurs from backend side (Django Rest Framework). But I still don't know how to submit the request as form-data in Angular way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample fileUploadService and a controller that calls it

```
services.service('fileUploadService', ['$http', function ($http) {
  this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl, params){
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', file);
    promise = $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
      transformRequest: angular.identity,
      headers: {'Content-Type': undefined},
      params: params
    });

    return promise;
  }
}]);
```

In your controller you can use the `fileUploadService` like so:

```
  $scope.sendToServer = function() {
    var uploadUrl = '/myUrl/';
    fileUploadService.uploadFileToUrl(
      $scope.croppedImage, uploadUrl, {}).then(function(resp) {
        // handle response
    })
  };
```

Comment: Thank for an example, let's me try.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to convert the image to Base64 to post the image to Django-Rest Framework.